# Is 'observation' method in 'ObservationWrapper' class of gym lib implicitly called?

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I found a problem during debugging the code of reinforcement learning model based on large language model (LLM). Generally, majority of plugins or other software for research on reinforcement learning are practically developed based on gym, with which the class will be firstly packaged then deployed for different requirements. Especially, the 'Wrapper' class supply a great functionality of different parameters such as observations or actions for rebuliding.
When I was reviewing the details of Wrapper class, I noticed a problem below:

```
class DiscreteToBoxWrapper(gym.ObservationWrapper):
    def __init__(self, env):
        super().__init__(env)
        assert isinstance(env.observation_space, gym.spaces.Discrete), \
            "Should only be used to wrap Discrete envs."
        self.n = self.observation_space.n
        self.observation_space = gym.spaces.Box(0, 1, (self.n,))
    
    def observation(self, obs): # seems this function is implicitly called?
    # is it the same situation as 'forward' function in nn.Module class?
        new_obs = np.zeros(self.n)
        new_obs[obs] = 1
        return new_obs

env = DiscreteToBoxWrapper(gym.make("FrozenLake-v1"))
T = 10
s_t = env.reset()
for t in range(T):
    a_t = env.action_space.sample()
    s_t, r_t, done, info = env.step(a_t)
    print(s_t)
    if done:
        s_t = env.reset()
```

Here, an observation-rebuilt env has been deployed in this code and this is the output:

```
[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
```

In contrast, if env variable is assigned by:

```
env = gym.make("FrozenLake-v1")
```

the output will be different:

```
1
5
1
0
4
0
4
0
4
8
```

Obviously, the expression of observations has been changed in 'observation' function. What is the most intriguing, however, is that there is not an explicit call of this function. When the Wrapper class is called, the observation has been modified automatically.
In my sight, another analogous phenomenon happens to the 'forward' function of nn.Module, in which the function will be called by `__call__` but not worked if immediately calling. But I cannot exactly assert that this is the same condition of 'observation' function (and other relative functions like action or reward wrappers). I hope somebody can help me to answer this or supply any advice for help. Many thanks!